# Getting rid of GET keys parameters in the URL, keep only values

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

I wanna to get rid of GET string parameters, from keys.

For example this is initial uri:

```
http://example.com/api/get_users_method?user_age_from=18&user_age_to=25&user_city=ohio
http://example.com/api/get_users_method?user_age_from=18&user_age_to=25 
http://example.com/api/get_users_method?user_city=ohio
```

I wanna make like this:

```
http://example.com/api/get_users_method/18/25/ohio 
http://example.com/api/get_users_method/18/25 
http://example.com/api/get_users_method/ohio
```

How can i get this result? I found some solution, to edit htaccess file, but it doesn't work unfortunately, maybe i made some mistakes in htacces file? I'm using php. Thanks!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /api/get_users_method?user_age_from=$1&user_age_to=$2&user_city=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /api/get_users_method?user_age_from=$1&user_age_to=$2&user_city=$3 [NC,L]
```

You have to treat the rules separately. All Conditions preceding rules only apply to a single rule. Following rules are not touched by that rule.

Comment: Hi @Denis if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will 3 separate rules in your root .htaccess (a level above `api` directory)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(api/get_users_method)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ $1?user_age_from=$2&user_age_to=$3&user_city=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(api/get_users_method)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ $1?user_age_from=$2&user_age_to=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(api/get_users_method)/(\w+)/?$ $1?user_city=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```